# Javascript and <form action>; totaling numbers inputted into textbox

Tags: javascript

Here is my code:

```
<script type = "text/javascript" >
    var apple_price = 5;
    var banana_price = 10;
    var orange_price = 15;

    function apple_subtotal (num_apple) //returns the cost of apples:
    {
        if (num_apple > 5 ) {
            return apple_price * num_apple * 0.9;
        } else {
            return apple_price * num_appl;
        }
    }

    function banana_subtotal (num_banana) //returns the cost of bananas:
    {
        if (num_banana > 5 ) {
            return banana_price * num_banana * 0.9;
        } else {
            return banana_price * num_banana;
        }
    }

    function orange_subtotal (num_orange) // Returns the cost of oranges:
    {
        if (num_orange > 5 ) {
            return orange_price * num_orange * 0.9;
        } else {
            return orange_price * num_orange;
        }
    }

    function grand_subtotal(num_apple, num_banana, num_orange) // returns the total cost of all items combined:
    {
        var a = apple_subtotal(num_apple);
        var b = banana_subtotal(num_banana);
        var c = orange_subtotal(num_orange);
        var d = num_apple + num_banana + num_orange;

        if (d > 10 ) {
            return (a + b + c) * 1.07 * 0.95;
        } else {
            return (a + b + c) * 1.07;
        }
    }
</script>

<form action="">
 Number of Apples: <input type="text"  name="apples" size="3"  /></br> <!-- Variable for    number of apples -->
 Number of Bananas: <input type="text"  name="bananas" size="3"  /></br> <!-- Variable for number of bananas -->
 Number of Oranges: <input type="text"  name="oranges" size="3" /></br> <!-- Variable for number of oranges -->
 <input type="button" value="total" onclick="document.forms[0].grand_total.value =   grand_subtotal(document.forms[0].apples.value, document.forms[0].bananas.value, document.forms[0].oranges.value)" /></br>         <!-- Button to calculate the grand total -->
Grand Total: $<input type="text" name="grand_total" /> <!-- Grand total display -->
</form>
```

Basically, the code I am writing is for a pretend online store for a class I am in. If you order over 10 items you get a 5% discount. My problem is I cannot get the total number counted correctly, instead the discount is always applied regardless of the amount purchased. Is there a way to extract the information in the form section and to call it to the grand sub total section where the calculations are being made?

Comment: which count ur checking for grand_total?? total number of items (banana+orange+apple) if total of 3 is more than 10 then u want apply discount?

Answer (score 0):

In your post you say " If you order over 10 items you get a 5% discount", but in the code you have:

```
if (num_apple > 5 ) {
  return apple_price * num_apple * 0.9;
}
```

so you are giving a discount for more than 5 items, not 10, and giving a 10% discount, not 5%. You can simplify this code using:

```
function apple_subtotal (num_apple) {
  return apple_price * num_apple * (num_apple > 10? 0.95 : 1);
}
```

But that applies the 10% discount to the entire order, not just those in excess of 10 (maybe that's what you want, maybe not).

Another issue is that form values are always strings, so when you do:

```
var d = num_apple + num_banana + num_orange;
```

you are concatenating the values, not adding them. So if someone orders 1 apple, 0 bananas and 0 oranges then you have:

```
var d = '1' + '0' + '0';  // '100'
```

To make the `+` operator do addition instead of concatenation, make them all numbers. Some options:

```
var d = +num_apple + +num_banana + +num_orange;

var d = Number(num_apple) + Number(num_banana) + Number(num_orange);

var d = parseInt(num_apple, 10) + parseInt(num_banana, 10) + parseInt(num_orange, 10);
```

You don't have this issue in the other functions as they don't do addition. With subtraction, division and multiplication operators, arguments are converted to numbers first (if they can be), even if they're strings.

Also, where you have:

```
<input type="button" value="total" onclick="document.forms[0].grand_total.value =   grand_subtotal(document.forms[0].apples.value, document.forms[0].bananas.value, document.forms[0].oranges.value)">
```

Note that form controls have a *form* property that references the form they are in, so:

```
<input type="button" value="total" onclick="
  this.form.grand_total.value = grand_subtotal(this.form.apples.value, this.form.bananas.value, this.form.oranges.value)">
```

but all that would be better in a separate function, not an in–line listener.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

Just replace your grand_subtotal function with this:

```
function grand_subtotal(num_apple, num_banana, num_orange) // returns the total cost of       all items combined:
    {
        var a = apple_subtotal(+num_apple);
        var b = banana_subtotal(+num_banana);
        var c = orange_subtotal(+num_orange);
        alert(c);
        var d = (+num_apple) + (+num_banana) + (+num_orange);
        if (d > 10) {
            return (a + b + c) * 1.07 * 0.95;
        }
        else {
            return (a + b + c) * 1.07;
        }
    }
```